# URL not changing redirection (primefaces + JSF 2.2)

Tags: redirect, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to make the navigation in my j2ee app working, the menuitem in the xhtml must make the url and page change and go to another xhtml page..
The problem is that when i push the button, nothing happens.. i don't know why, tried to return ?faces-redirect=true and to add redirect tag in the faces config but the redirection wont happen..
What could i've forgot ?
thanks

here is the code :

***xhtml :***

```
    <p:submenu label="Services">
    <p:menuitem value="Remise de Doc." actionListener="#{PagesController.remisetrEt}"  ajax="false" icon="ui-icon ui-icon-folder-open" />
    </p:submenu>
```

***faces-config :***

```
       <navigation-rule>
        <from-view-id>/accueil.xhtml</from-view-id>
       <navigation-case>
           <from-outcome>logout</from-outcome>
             <to-view-id>/index.xhtml</to-view-id>
             <redirect/>
       </navigation-case>
       <navigation-case>
       <from-action>#{PagesController.remisetrEt}</from-action>
           <from-outcome>remisetret</from-outcome>
             <to-view-id>/remisetrEt.xhtml</to-view-id>
             <redirect/>     
       </navigation-case>
        </navigation-rule>
```

***the bean method :***

```
public String remisetrEt()
    {
        return "remisetret?faces-redirect=true";
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a `<h:form />` wrapped around the submenu-tag?

Comment: thx for the answer, yeap, i have a form